# Powershell script to print certain pages of a file

Tags: powershell

Im trying to create a powershell script that will print a certain page of a document, i know the command for printing an entire file is as follows

```
start-process -FilePath $file.fullName -Verb Print
```

but i only want the second to last page of the document to be printed
Thanks

Comment: I believe that you would need to use a program that exposed an interface of some sort for this. MS Word for instance.

Comment: How do you decide where pages stop and start?

Answer (score 1):

If its a word doc its difficult but not impossible if you know the relevant page no's using the Application.PrintOut Method. You do need to populate the printout field up to pages as shown.

```
# Open Word Document 
$FileName = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Example.docx"
$Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$Word.Visible  = $true # Use $false to not show document
$word.Documents.Open($FileName)

#Print required Page
$Missing    = [System.Reflection.Missing]::Value  # use default parameter values
$BackGround = 1
$Append     = 1
$Range      = $Word.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count     # Number of pages in range
$OutputFileName = $Missing
$From       = $Missing
$To     = $Missing
$Item       = 0
$Copies     = 1     # Number of Print Copies
$Penultimate = $Range-1
$Pages      = "$Penultimate"   # Print penultimate page only

$Word.printout([ref]$BackGround, [ref]$Append, [ref]$Range, [ref]$OutputFileName, [ref]$From, [ref]$To, [ref]$Item, [ref]$Copies, [ref]$Pages)

# Close Word
$Word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WordDoc)
```